# Limit number of links in a string (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, limit

I've just started allowing guest posts on my blog, but to avoid spam I would like to automatically limit the number of links per post.

If an author creates more than 3 links, the rest should be removed, but the anchor text should   not be removed.

Is this possible?

Best Regards
Kim Kristensen

EDIT:

Thanks for your replies. I have now come to the following solution:

```
$html = 'hejsdjhf ksdfh ksdhf ksdfh klsfh kldjfh klsdfh ksdfh ksdfh ksdfh ksd <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a> dkhjdfjkgh ksdfhg ksdhf kjsdhfkg jhsdfklgh sdlfkg <a href="http://www.test.com">test2</a> skdjfh kgh kshg kdjh gklhf gkldhg kjsdfhgk hjsdfkg hdkgh dksfgh ksdfhg ksdhf g <a href="http://www.test.com">test3</a>';

$regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
if(preg_match_all($regexp, $html, $matches)) {
    $link_count = count($matches[2]);
}

//echo $link_count;
$limit = $link_count - 2;

$regexp = "/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";
echo preg_replace($regexp, "$2", $html, $limit);
```

I don't know whether it is hugely effective, but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You could look for anchor tags endings (`</a>`) in a `for` loop using the `strpos ()` function and have a counter for the number of anchors you find. When you reach three, simply split the string into two parts at the place when the last `strpos ()` was found (+4 for the length of "`</a>`") and use `strip_tags ()` on the rest of  the string.

EDIT: 
Something like this:

```
define ('MAX_ANCHOR', 3);
define ('ANCHOR_ENDING', '</a>');

$counter = 0;
$strposResult = 0;
do {
  $strposResult = $strposResult === FALSE ? FALSE : strpos ($string, ANCHOR_ENDING, $strposResult) + strlen (ANCHOR_ENDING);
  $counter++;
} while ($counter < MAX_ANCHOR && $strposResult !== FALSE);

if ($counter == MAX_ANCHOR) {
  $firstHalf = substr ($string, 0, $strposResult);
  $secondHalf = substr ($string, $strposResult);
  $string = $firstHalf . strip_tags ($secondHalf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in PHP

```
preg_match_all('/\<a[^>]+>/i',$html, $result);
```

This regex will catch you all the link tag and set it on the $result var.

you just have to work with this var to count how link tag you have